# Datagrid row text into 1 textbox

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

I want to add datagrid row (which consists of 2 columns with strings) into single textbox on different form.So far I can see only 1 value in my textbox, second one isn't displayed. Here's my code:

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEnter(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellEnter

        Dim i As Integer
        i = DataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index

        Dim a
        Dim b

        a = DataGridView1(0, i).Value.ToString
        b = DataGridView1(1, i).Value.ToString

        Form2.TextBox1.Text = a + b

    End Sub
```

Any help appreciated !

Comment: Set a breakpoint at 'Form2.TextBox1.Text = a + b' and have a look at what is going on.

Comment: I think i figured out what is happening... DB table fields are set to 30 char. When pulling data from It, empty spaces are added too.Nothing wrong with my code, I just had to stretch textbox quite wider. Any options to ignore empty spaces from DB fields ? Data being pulled are just names and surnames. i want to add them in textbox together.

Comment: Add .Trim() after your ToString()

Comment: Thanks, that solved it.You can post an answer if you want.